# How to generate code for the getters using a PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

This question is totally depends on my previous question. Link to that question as mentioned as follows. ([Interface projection in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77396267/interface-projection-in-spring-boot/77396521?noredirect=1#comment136454044_77396521))

I have to map database columns to getters like below:

```
interface UserAccess {
        Optional<Long> getUserId();
        Optional<String> getUserName();
        Optional<Long> getRoleId();
        Optional<String> getRoleName();
        Optional<Boolean> getUserRoleReadOnly();
        Optional<Long> getFormId();
        Optional<String> getFormName();
        Optional<String> getUrlPath();
        Optional<Boolean> getFormAccessReadOnly();
        Optional<Long> getFormTabId();
        Optional<String> getFormTabName();
        Optional<Boolean> getFormTabAccessReadOnly();
        Optional<Long> getBranchId();
        Optional<String> getBranchName();
        Optional<Boolean> getBranchAccessReadOnly();
        Optional<Long> getEntityId();
        Optional<String> getEntityName();
        Optional<Boolean> getEntityAccessReadOnly();
        Optional<Long> getOrgId();
        Optional<String> getOrgName();
    }
```

and I can do it manually. However, it requires a lot of labor implementing such getters. I was told that this can be done via code generation. I wonder how this could be done via SQL.

How can I do it?

Comment: There are many ways to generate code, and many ways to inspect a database schema. Too many to describe here. But one example that brings the two together is the jOOQ code generator. You could look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the code:

## Schema

```
CREATE TABLE my_test(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_name VARCHAR(32),
    "Count" INT,
    is_deleted BOOLEAN
);
```

The above is an example only.

## Query

```
SELECT
      'Optional<' ||
       CASE
           WHEN data_type = 'integer' THEN 'Long'
           WHEN data_type = 'character varying' THEN 'String'
           WHEN data_type = 'boolean' THEN 'Boolean'
           ELSE data_type
       END ||
       '> get' ||
       replace(initcap(replace(column_name, '_', ' ')), ' ', '') ||
       '();' AS script
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_schema = 'public'
   AND table_name   = 'my_test'
;
```

## Fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/45c0a8/10

## Explanation

- `information_schema.columns` is a `table` which contains information about database `columns`
- we select our `my_test` `table` from the `public` schema, you of course might have different tables and different schemas, feel free to replace this accordingly
- we do the code generation in the `SELECT` clause via generating a string with `data_type` and `column_name` as the inputs and concatenating the parts
- the case-when part resolves the type mapping and this is just a proof-of-concept, you may have many more different data types, so please take into account that this is a proof-of-concept only and not the actual implementation, this is why non-integers, for example were not handled here, not nullability
- `replace(initcap(replace(column_name, '_', ' ')), ' ', '')` converts a snake-cased name, such as `user_name` into camel-cased name, such as `UserName`, so, when your query concatenates this to "get", you will end up with something like `getUserName()`

## Result

It should look something like this:

[image]

and we have successfully written code that writes code for us, which will particularly be useful if there are thousands and thousands of columns to implement getters for.